# Any way to force reset of chests in the Lost Realm?

Tags: castle-clash

I usually have lots of Bronze keys, and no Silver or Gold key, yet "stuck" with silver/gold chests that appear often.

I know the chests reset themselves every 2 hours, but is there a way to force reset (presumably by paying Gems), like we can reset other things e.g. Trade Shop?

I tried long press a chest, looking for some hidden menu... to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to force reset a chest.

What you can do is spend gems to refresh your warehouse, and then buy silver / gold keys from there.

Comment: I suspected that's the case. Thanks for the warehouse refresh tip, didn't think of that, however this requires Merits which are hard to get.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, you could try doing the daily achievements, which will give you a Merit Box II (or something like that) one day, which contains 5k Merits.

Comment: @PythonMaster yup, 5k once a month is nice, but enough for only few keys. Solid tip though, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is rather old question, and it is rather comment than an answer ( I cannot comment, yet). 
I am not sure what might you had at the time but I am assuming quite low. From my experience (over 160k might) the key issue will change by 180 degrees. I have a lot of gold and silver keys but barely bronze...

Comment: Indeed, with higher might one indeed gets better loot/prized, but that's not really answering the actual question. I was at very low might back  then, think around 20k maybe even less.